# add strings to a user input on text change - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have an asp:textbox named txtPolicyNumber. and the normal input is PC-000000000012
I want it to be when a user inputs, PC-12 in would be converted to PC-000000000012 when the user leave the textbox (on text change) how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">
function replace()
{
var number=document.getElementById('huh').value;
var first=number.substr(0,number.indexOf('-')+1);
var final=first+"0000000000"+number.substring(number.indexOf('-')+1);
alert(final);//final contains ->PC-000000000012
}
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="huh" runat="server" onblur="replcae()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the format D (The number after the D is the amount of digits to display) option like this:

```
int value;

value = 12345;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("D"));
// Displays 12345
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("D8"));
// Displays 00012345
```

From:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString

Answer (score 0):

There's an event named "[onBlur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)" (javascript event) use that event, and add a javascript that will convert the user input, like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
function test(){

}
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="huh" runat="server" onblur="test()"/>
```